# JavaEE on NetBeans 7.4 GlassFish 4 not deployed

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I create a JavaEE project its name EnterpriseApplication6
I create a New SessionBean in EnterpriseApplication6-ejb its name NewSessionBean and its Session type stateless with local interface
I creaet a New Servlet in EnterpriseApplication6-war its name NewServlet
The problem occure when I declare the NewSessionBean in NewServlet then this error will appear :
1- NewServlet will run like this[]:(https://www.dropbox.com/s/rssmhvtu5kzor05/Untitled.png)
2- and this error appear
This is the error
C:\Users\AdminPC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EnterpriseApplication6\nbproject\build-impl.xml:307: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.

when I delete the declaration the project will be Ok
How can I solve this problem?

NewServlet code:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package b;

import bbb.NewSessionBean;
import bbb.NewSessionBeanLocal;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author AdminPC
 */


@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @EJB
    NewSessionBeanLocal g;
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + g.show() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: Which URL you are using to view output?

Comment: Show your NerServlet & NewSessionBean code.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rssmhvtu5kzor05/Untitled.png

Comment: Are you used URL like : http://localhost:8080/application/NewServlet?

Comment: this URL http://localhost:8080/EnterpriseApplication6-war/NewServlet

Comment: Add your server.log for details...

Comment: I have also experienced same problem in Java EE project of Netbeans.

Comment: Please Answer me about solution :)